# jquery: possible to select an item only if it's followed by an item with a specific class?

Tags: jquery

the problem:

I want to use jquery to add a class of 'warm' to any li's neighboring to a li.hot

```
<ul>
    <li></li> * ? (unknown amount of li's)
    <li></li>
    <li class="hot"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li> * ? (unknown amount of li's)
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "neighboring", you meant the previous and next elements then you can use **[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** and **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** selectors.

```
var liHot = $("li.hot");
liHot.prev("li").addClass("warm");
liHot.next("li").addClass("warm");
```

Comment: and in one statement: $('li.hot').prev("li").addClass("warm").end().next('li').addClass('warm');

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.hot').prev().addClass('warm');
$('li.hot').next().addClass('warm');
```

I know it's basic, but you get the idea.